# How to start chrome browser in already logged in tab using chrome drivers via selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, stay-logged-in

I need to API WhatsApp web using selenium and chrome drivers or other drivers but it is not possible to open an already scanned WhatsApp-web page. I need to scan every time I run the code. I need suggestion for selenium of any other alternatives for selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(https://web.whatsapp.com)
```

I tried
1)chrome default page as WhatsApp-web logged in
2)not possible to change the URL of WhatsApp web but it is not possible as WhatsApp is single paged website.
3)cant access logged in cache also

Comment: You can use an existing cookie. You can also log in using selenium after starting the new browser. You cannot, however, just "attach" selenium to an existing logged in webpage on your system.

Answer (score 0):

you just needs to scan the QR code for one time, using user-data-dir you are able to save your session in chrome profile and use it anytime

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\mywhatsapp")
whatsapp = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Windows\System32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
whatsapp.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```